# Standalone adds extra to paper width and height

Tags: pdftex, pdf, standalone, includegraphics, paper-size

I want to convert two or more pictures file into `pdf`. Searching in `TEX.SE` it suggested the following (`TexLive 2021`, `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass[multi=page]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{page}
            \centering\includegraphics[width=5.39in,height=8.46in]{C:/Users/.../Downloads/Images/1}
\end{page}
\begin{page}
                \centering\includegraphics[width=5.39in,height=8.46in]{C:/Users/.../Downloads/Images/2}
    \end{page}
\end{document}
```

but it changes the paper size to `5.47x8.47`! I tried

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=5.39in,
    paperheight=8.46in,
    margin=0in
}
```

also

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt},multi=page]{standalone}
```

without any success.

[image]

Is that possible to prevent adding this extra amount to page size in `standalone`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding spaces, hide them with %:

```
\documentclass[multi=page]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{page}%%<----
\includegraphics[width=5.39in,height=8.46in]{example-image-duck}%%<---
\end{page}
\end{document}
```